# Do the planetary ring lasts?

Tags: solar-system, planet, gas-giants, planetary-ring

Almost all gas giants in our solar system are observed to have a planetary ring comprises of ice, dust and rocks. My question is do these rings obediently sticks around their foster parent until our starving Sun becomes red giant? Also why don't the ring forms into moon?